# Fastest way for creating nested arrays from single array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, fs, tostring

I have a huge list of data in .txt file. I'm reading it with node.js fs.readFile and when i get the data as data.toString() i get something like this:

```
II IY 9C JD 2D QC QY 6Y 3C ID
KI JI 2Y 6Y 5Y QY QI 3Y 7C 6D
TC 3Y 4I 7Y QC 2Y 3I 8C JI KH
AH 8H 5I 4C 9H JD 3H 7I JC AC
```

I would need to create a nested arrays splited in five of each row. It should look like this:

```
[
[[["I","I"] ["I","Y"] ["9","C"] ["J","D"] ["2","D"]], [["Q","C"] ["Q","Y"] ["6","Y"] ["3","C"] ["I","D"]]]
[[["K","I"] ["J","I"] ["2","Y"] ["6","Y"] ["5","Y"]], [["Q","Y"] ["Q","I"] ["3","Y"] ["7","C"] ["6","D"]]]
[[["T","C"] ["3","Y"] ["4","I"] ["7","Y"] ["Q","C"]], [["2","Y"] ["3","I"] ["8","C"] ["J","I"] ["K","H"]]]
[[["A","H"] ["8","H"] ["5","I"] ["4","C"] ["9","H"]], [["J","D"] ["3","H"] ["7","I"] ["J","C"] ["A","C"]]]
]
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Edit:

Current code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
  fs.readFile(path, async (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(data.toString());
  });
```

File snippet:

```
8C TS KC 9H 4S 7D 2S 5D 3S AC
5C AD 5D AC 9C 7C 5H 8D TD KS
3H 7H 6S KC JS QH TD JC 2D 8S
TH 8H 5C QS TC 9H 4D JC KS JS
7C 5H KC QH JD AS KH 4C AD 4S
5H KS 9C 7D 9H 8D 3S 5D 5C AH
6H 4H 5C 3H 2H 3S QH 5S 6S AS
TD 8C 4H 7C TC KC 4C 3H 7S KS
7C 9C 6D KD 3H 4C QS QC AC KH
JC 6S 5H 2H 2D KD 9D 7C AS JS
AD QH TH 9D 8H TS 6D 3S AS AC
2H 4S 5C 5S TC KC JD 6C TS 3C
QD AS 6H JS 2C 3D 9H KC 4H 8S
KD 8S 9S 7C 2S 3S 6D 6S 4H KC
3C 8C 2D 7D 4D 9S 4S QH 4H JD
8C KC 7S TC 2D TS 8H QD AC 5C
3D KH QD 6C 6S AD AS 8H 2H QS
6S 8D 4C 8S 6C QH TC 6D 7D 9D
```

Comment: how does the input relate to the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you the expected output of multiple sets of 2 groups of 5 items

```js
let data = `II IY 9C JD 2D QC QY 6Y 3C ID
KI JI 2Y 6Y 5Y QY QI 3Y 7C 6D
TC 3Y 4I 7Y QC 2Y 3I 8C JI KH
AH 8H 5I 4C 9H JD 3H 7I JC AC`;

let nested = data.split("\n").map(l => ([
  [...l.split(" ").filter((n, i) => i < 5).map(n => n.split(''))],
  [...l.split(" ").filter((n, i) => i >= 5).map(n => n.split(''))]
]))

console.log(nested)

// or even more concise

const gset = (grp,setn) => [...grp.split(" ").filter((n, i) => setn == 0 ? (i < 5) : (i>=5)).map(n => n.split(''))]
let nested2 = data.split("\n").map(g => ([gset(g,0), gset(g,1)]))
console.log('More concise version:', nested2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do some string manipulation, especially `split()`.

## Update

The answer didn't seem to satisfy the OP's question. Here's the actual version:

```js
const data = 
`8C TS KC 9H 4S 7D 2S 5D 3S AC
5C AD 5D AC 9C 7C 5H 8D TD KS
3H 7H 6S KC JS QH TD JC 2D 8S
TH 8H 5C QS TC 9H 4D JC KS JS
7C 5H KC QH JD AS KH 4C AD 4S
5H KS 9C 7D 9H 8D 3S 5D 5C AH
6H 4H 5C 3H 2H 3S QH 5S 6S AS
TD 8C 4H 7C TC KC 4C 3H 7S KS
7C 9C 6D KD 3H 4C QS QC AC KH
JC 6S 5H 2H 2D KD 9D 7C AS JS
AD QH TH 9D 8H TS 6D 3S AS AC
2H 4S 5C 5S TC KC JD 6C TS 3C
QD AS 6H JS 2C 3D 9H KC 4H 8S
KD 8S 9S 7C 2S 3S 6D 6S 4H KC
3C 8C 2D 7D 4D 9S 4S QH 4H JD
8C KC 7S TC 2D TS 8H QD AC 5C
3D KH QD 6C 6S AD AS 8H 2H QS
6S 8D 4C 8S 6C QH TC 6D 7D 9D`;
const lines = data.split("\n"); // Each line will be an array value
let result = []; // Define our result
lines.forEach(item => {
  let current = [];
  let now = item.split(" ");
  let fir = [];
  let sec = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < now.length; i++) {
    if(i < 5) fir.push(now[i].split(""));
    else sec.push(now[i].split(""));
  }
  current.push(fir);
  current.push(sec);
  result.push(current);
});
console.log(result);
```

## Old version

```js
const data = 
`8C TS KC 9H 4S 7D 2S 5D 3S AC
5C AD 5D AC 9C 7C 5H 8D TD KS
3H 7H 6S KC JS QH TD JC 2D 8S
TH 8H 5C QS TC 9H 4D JC KS JS
7C 5H KC QH JD AS KH 4C AD 4S
5H KS 9C 7D 9H 8D 3S 5D 5C AH
6H 4H 5C 3H 2H 3S QH 5S 6S AS
TD 8C 4H 7C TC KC 4C 3H 7S KS
7C 9C 6D KD 3H 4C QS QC AC KH
JC 6S 5H 2H 2D KD 9D 7C AS JS
AD QH TH 9D 8H TS 6D 3S AS AC
2H 4S 5C 5S TC KC JD 6C TS 3C
QD AS 6H JS 2C 3D 9H KC 4H 8S
KD 8S 9S 7C 2S 3S 6D 6S 4H KC
3C 8C 2D 7D 4D 9S 4S QH 4H JD
8C KC 7S TC 2D TS 8H QD AC 5C
3D KH QD 6C 6S AD AS 8H 2H QS
6S 8D 4C 8S 6C QH TC 6D 7D 9D`;
const lines = data.split("\n"); // Each line will be an array value
let result = []; // Define our result
lines.forEach(item => {
  let current = [];
  let now = item.split(" ");
  let fir = [];
  let sec = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < now.length; i++) {
    if(i < 5) fir.push(now[i].split(""));
    else sec.push(now[i].split(""));
  }
  current.push(fir);
  current.push(sec);
  result.push(current);
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Did it work? If it did, could you please select it as the answer?

Comment: @Kinglish fixed.

Comment: @RobinGrundel please see the updated example.

Answer (score 1):

`split()` is what you want to use.

```js
let data = `II IY 9C JD 2D QC QY 6Y 3C ID
KI JI 2Y 6Y 5Y QY QI 3Y 7C 6D
TC 3Y 4I 7Y QC 2Y 3I 8C JI KH
AH 8H 5I 4C 9H JD 3H 7I JC AC`;

const createArray = (str) => {
    const splitedByLines = str.split('\n');
    const splitedByBlank = splitedByLines.map(line => line.split(' '));
    const result = splitedByBlank.map(line => line.map(e => e.split('')));
    return result;
}

console.log(createArray(data));
```

You can even make everything in one line:

```js
let data = `II IY 9C JD 2D QC QY 6Y 3C ID
KI JI 2Y 6Y 5Y QY QI 3Y 7C 6D
TC 3Y 4I 7Y QC 2Y 3I 8C JI KH
AH 8H 5I 4C 9H JD 3H 7I JC AC`;

const createArray2 = str => str.split('\n').map(line => line.split(' ')).map(line => line.map(e => e.split('')));

console.log(createArray2(data));
```